Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated and will be removed in the next major release
i am using react ant design when i am trying to supply menu object to Menu Component it is showng e this error.
i have tried it so many time but unfortunatily i am unable to fix this
chunk-YI7ZP7WZ.js?v=389dc965:521 Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated and will be removed in the next major release. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference. Learn more about using refs safely here: https://reactjs.org/link/strict-mode-find-node
i was tring to create navigation bar with react ant design using vite compiler, but i am face the warning.

findDOMNode( ) method was used to search the tree of a DOM node. This method is deprecated in React. Hence, the StrictMode gives us a warning about the usage of this method
